# Does import everything from Java enum package leads to performance issues?

Tags: java, performance, package

Does import everything from Java enum package leads to performance issues?

Like I have an enum package contains 50 Enums. But in a class i need to use around 5 - 10.

```
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum1;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum2;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum3;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum4;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum5;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum6;
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.Enum7;
```

or is it fine to use:

```
import fn.gomal.process.model.enums.*;
```

If there is performance issue using * then what impact will it have? Is the performance impact happens during build time or compile time or run time?

Comment: 'Package' or 'Enum package' doesn't make any difference. Pointless edit.

Comment: My point was that only but i asked more generic question. Not expecting this to reopen as i already got answer. ;)